# Getting current location timezone

Tags: android, timezone

On Android how can I obtain timezone offset from UTC based on my current location? I dont want to use any 3rd party web service or include tz_world database to my app.

If I move acrros timezone border, my phone changes time automatically. Is it possible to obtain the offset absed on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone: "+tz.getDisplayName());
```

Answer (score 3):

Since time zones tend to have summer time (DST) and other anomalies, there is a difference between obtaining the time zone and obtaining the offset from UTC. The latter requires not only a location, but also a time of year.

The modern way to obtain the time zone:

```
    ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

On my Mac I got `Europe/Copenhagen`. Beware, however, that what this gives you, is the time zone setting of your JVM. This won’t change when the device’s setting changes. To make matters worse, the JVM setting may be changed from other parts of your program or from other programs running in the same JVM. Only when the JVM is restarted, it will pick up the device setting.

To get the current offset from UTC:

```
    ZoneOffset offsetFromUtc = timeZone.getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
```

In my case I got `+01:00`. Pass a different `Instant` if you want the offset from another time of year.

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. I am told that it’s built in on newer Android devices. To use it on an older device, get ThreeTenABP, add it to your project and make sure you import the date and time classes from the `org.threeten.bp` package. See the links below.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.